# Javascript Function Object (Call to a property from a function that inside a function object)

Tags: javascript, function, oop

Wondering What im doing wrong,
I want to call to a property that belong to a function object, from a function inside a function object.

When I check the value of "problems" variable, it stays "0".

This is my code(object declare):

```
function ValidateClass () {
    this.messege = "";
    this.problems = 0;

    this.getResults = function () {
            alert (this.problems);
        if (this.problems > 0) {
            
            showAlertModal(this.messege);
            return false;
        }
    }

    this.CompareDates = function (parent) {
        
        $(parent).each(function () {
            
            let startDate = $(this).find($(".datepickercheckin")).datepicker("getDate");
            let endDate = $(this).find($(".datepickercheckout")).datepicker("getDate");
            if (endDate === null) {
                endDate = startDate
            }

            if (endDate < startDate) {

                this.messege += '<span class="note"><i class="fas fa-sad-tear w3-small"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;End date cannot be earlier or equal to Start date</span><br>';
                this.problems += 1;
                return false;
                
            }
            
        })
        
    }
}


The instance of the function object:

let validate = new ValidateClass();
validate.CompareDates($(".perioddiv"));
let result = validate.getResults();
```

Comment: Can we see your HTML?

Comment: You can't expect `$(this)` to refer to an HTML element and `this` to your `ValidateClass` instance…

Comment: Alright , Make sense , do you have any idea how to overcome this problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20279485/476

Comment: Thank you, This Is solved. Changed  this to self.
let self = this. 
and then use self as a reference to "this"